# 3way wiring help

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting

I am trying to figure out wiring for a 3-way switch controlling a large chandelier. I have multiple other 3-ways and 4-ways that I was able to get working without any issues. This config has me thrown for a loop.   I am using GE Enbrighten Zwave dimmer + GE Enbrighten Addon switches.

Box 1
12-3 red hot, white has black elec tape (which I was hoping to use as a neutral to Box 2 for aux), black cold
12-2 which I believe goes to the light fixture. this is a shared junction box with another light and the second 12-2 in the box powers that light.
12-2 providing power to another set of lights in the room, no issues with this
[image: box 1]

Box 2
12-3, the red and black show hot. white is in elec tape (would like to pull neutral from Box 1 using this)
[image: box 2]

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the fixture junction box please?

Comment: Don't suppose you took pictures before you disconnected everything, did you?

Comment: The white with tape is NOT a neutral. It is switched hot in a switch loop. It would be used to turn the lights on/off.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel  I actually cant get to it easily. It's a massive chandelier and will probably require 3 people to get it down.

Comment: @Ruskes  I know, but I was hoping to do a little rewiring to use it as a neutral, as my 2nd box location doesn't have one currently.

Comment: @jack  Unfortunately, I don't.  I was just using it a single switch.  Just had some time this weekend and was hoping to try to nail this.

Comment: If you are not going to use the 3 way switches, you could repurpose that wiring.

Comment: @4way   Only white or grey wires can be used for neutral.  Cannot mark other colours for neutral(no blacks or reds with white tape/paint).  A white wire can be marked for a hot wire, but not the other way

Comment: Re-defining former travelers for smart switches is fine. The question is how the original wiring was done.  Note that you aren't allowed to steal neutral from unrelated groups of wires; you can only take neutral from cables *which already have at least 1 wire going to that switch*.  So we need to see how the 3-way group is wired to see if neutral can even be found.

Comment: Find out if that white with tape was used as traveler on 3 way switch.

Comment: Where does power come into this mess from?

Comment: Check some instructions here: https://manuals.plus/enbrighten/46199-in-wall-add-on-switch-manual#axzz7hpaw6SLX